# Probability puzzle - similar to brownian, simpler

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

On a bridge are $n$ stations, equally spaced.
Meaning $A_0$ is the left exit of the bridge, $A_1$ is $1$ distance unit (let's say meters) away from that, $A_2$ is $1$ meter away from that and so on, until $A_{99}$ which is the right exit of the bridge.

You are at $A_i$. You are quite an eccentric fellow, and each time you walk somewhere, you have $p$ probability to walk left and $1-p$ probability to walk right.

What is the probability you will exit the bridge from $A_0$? What is the probability you will exit from $A_{99}$?

Comment: This is a rephrasing of the [Gambler's Ruin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Comment: This is a typical Markov chain theory question. Do you have any experience with Markov chains?

Comment: Your current formulation has you on the bridge forever. Do you get off at a predetermined time? At every step with some probability?

Comment: You don't necessarily need to get off. im just asking what is the probability you will get to $A_0$ or $A_{99}$. I have no experience with markov chains